# Story read in the 70s about a human who is transformed into a cyborg or Steve Austin type being

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cyborg

I read a sci-fi story about 50 years ago and I at times wonder what story it was.

The only elements I remember is the main character was enhanced like the six million dollar man, and I remember a sentence mentioning his silver veins.  He was able to move very fast, etc.

I don't remember the final ending.  It was in a collection of sci-fi stories.  Not a lot of clues, but I'm at a loss what story it was.

Comment: It's funny you tagged this "cyborg" because the original novel on which *The Six Million Dollar Man* was based was called [*Cyborg*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4753).  But it wasn't a short story, and it didn't have silver veins.

Comment: The fellow who wrote *Cyborg* also wrote *Manfac*, which was a somewhat more realistic take.

Comment: Too recent, but *A Futuristic Cyborg Sci-fi Romance* Candice Gilmer: "Where it was, though, ... Silver veins ran through him, outlining the metallic pieces under his skin"

Comment: It wasn't a comic strip in, say [2000 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.A.C.H._1) was it?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the "Ryder Hook" series by Kenneth Bulmer (as by "Tully Zetford"). https://www.goodreads.com/series/149021-hook, starting with "Whirlpool of Stars" (1974). The main character has been 'boosted' with extra strength and speed, but he was an experimental version and the final result ("The Boosted Men") have even more abilities and are taking over the galaxy.

Comment: I believe you are right! I ordered a copy of "Whirlpool of Stars" to confirm this. The book timing is right 1974. And I remember there was an improved group of enhanced beings he was competing against towards the end. I had given up hope on identifying the book, but this seems like it.